# Backup Users/logins in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-administration

My client is working on a security project where in any user outside of DBA tean has sysadmin in DB or server level / dbo owner rights and remove the elevated permissions in all the SQL Servers. Before doing so we would like to backup the security just in case if something breaks. Can anyone help with the script? I have sp_rev_login for backuping up logins but thinking of using a pretty simple and straight forward solutions. Any ideas are welcome. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Taken from [Technet](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-logins-databases-816f66b2) Script center,this script gives us users,roles,object permissions as well

```
**--Server level Logins and roles**
SELECT sp.name AS LoginName,sp.type_desc AS LoginType, sp.default_database_name AS DefaultDBName,slog.sysadmin AS SysAdmin,slog.securityadmin AS SecurityAdmin,slog.serveradmin AS ServerAdmin, slog.setupadmin AS SetupAdmin, slog.processadmin AS ProcessAdmin, slog.diskadmin AS DiskAdmin, slog.dbcreator AS DBCreator,slog.bulkadmin AS BulkAdmin
FROM sys.server_principals sp  JOIN master..syslogins slog
ON sp.sid=slog.sid 
WHERE sp.type  <> 'R' AND sp.name NOT LIKE '##%'

--Databases users and roles
DECLARE @SQLStatement VARCHAR(4000) 
DECLARE @T_DBuser TABLE (DBName SYSNAME, UserName SYSNAME, AssociatedDBRole NVARCHAR(256)) 
SET @SQLStatement='
SELECT ''?'' AS DBName,dp.name AS UserName,USER_NAME(drm.role_principal_id) AS AssociatedDBRole 
FROM ?.sys.database_principals dp
LEFT OUTER JOIN ?.sys.database_role_members drm
ON dp.principal_id=drm.member_principal_id 
WHERE dp.sid NOT IN (0x01) AND dp.sid IS NOT NULL AND dp.type NOT IN (''C'') AND dp.is_fixed_role <> 1 AND dp.name NOT LIKE ''##%'' AND ''?'' NOT IN (''master'',''msdb'',''model'',''tempdb'') ORDER BY DBName'
INSERT @T_DBuser
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @SQLStatement
SELECT * FROM @T_DBuser ORDER BY DBName

--Get objects permission of specified user database 
USE <Database Name>
GO
DECLARE @Obj VARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @T_Obj TABLE (UserName SYSNAME, ObjectName SYSNAME, Permission NVARCHAR(128))
SET @Obj='
SELECT Us.name AS username, Obj.name AS object,  dp.permission_name AS permission 
FROM sys.database_permissions dp
JOIN sys.sysusers Us 
ON dp.grantee_principal_id = Us.uid 
JOIN sys.sysobjects Obj
ON dp.major_id = Obj.id '
INSERT @T_Obj 
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @Obj

SELECT * FROM @T_Obj
```

**Sample Output:**

```
DBName  UserName    AssociatedDBRole
PerformanceV3   public  NULL
PerformanceV3   dbo db_owner
PerformanceV3   guest   NULL
```

Comment: I want to backup the security of the user so in case if i need the security back i should be able to restore that with the script. In other words script to create the users/logins with the same security

Answer (score 0):

Use the generate scripts task and select users. Save the script as a file as a backup.

To find logins that have SA that shouldn't.

```sql
SELECT  'ALTER SERVER ROLE [sysadmin] DROP MEMBER [' + syslogins.name + '] GO;'
FROM    sys.syslogins
WHERE syslogins.name NOT IN (<dba GROUP/logins>)
```

That should be good enough for generating the remove SA. You could stick the output into a temp table and run a cursor over it to execute the removes if you don't want to copy/paste.

Comment: We are working on around 1800 SQL Servers a 20,000+ databases. Instead of using generate script task we are trying to provide some kind of automation to backup security before we drop users/logins

Comment: @Ramya Then you will need to multi-query all of those servers with a permissions generation script. Of which, there are several versions already out there and here on SO. You can do this in SSMS or setup a simple application that pulls from your list of servers and dumps the permissions into a file or table. However, if you are running SQL backups, your permissions are in the backup, but it sounds like you are wanting security only backups for an extended period of time.

Comment: Do you mind giving me some links where in the similar requirement is achieved?I can write a ssis package to get data from all the servers. I need only sql scripts to perform my requirement